# SharePoint DateTime conversion issue in ASP.NET

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, asp.net, .net

I am facing a strange issue in converting `DateTime` value received from SharePoint `GetListItems` method.

Here is what the date string looks like - `ows_DatePaid="2015-04-28T18:30:00Z".`

Now the problem is I had set date to `29-April` and not to `28-April` which I am receiving.

I have used following method to convert received DateTime.

```
public static DateTime ConvertFromSharePointTimeToDateTime(this string dateTimeStringToConvert)
{
      string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";
      histryViewModel.InsertHistory("Received DateTime:", dateTimeStringToConvert);
      var converted = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeStringToConvert, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      histryViewModel.InsertHistory("Converted DateTime:", converted.ToString());
      return converted;
}
```

When I browse Site from Visual Studio on my Local Machine it displays 29-April correctly.

SharePoint Server Time Zone is `Eastern US and Canada`.
Website deployment server timezone is UTC.
Local Machine Time Zone is `UTC +5.30 Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi.`

Please guide me on how do effectively display same date on my Site.

What is correct way to handle this problem? 
Feel free to suggest me changes, so that I can improve my method.

Comment: I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below snippet to convert it programmatically

```
SPRegionalSettings regionalSettings = web.RegionalSettings;
SPTimeZone timeZone = regionalSettings.TimeZone;

timeZone.UTCToLocalTime(dateTimeObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

- Open the site on which you want to change the regional settings.
- On the **Site Actions** menu, choose **Site Settings**.
- On the Site Settings page, under **Site Administration**, choose **Regional
  settings**.
- On the Regional Settings page, select the settings that you want for
  this site, and then choose the **OK** button

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint stores dates in UTC so when you insert a date in your local time it will be converted to UTC, when you fetch the date/time it will be returned in UTC so you have to take this in consideration. See url below how to fix this.

> Microsoft SharePoint Foundation stores date and time values in
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) format, and almost all date and time
>   values that are returned by members of the object model are in UTC
>   format. The one exception is list column values that are obtained
>   through the indexer for the SPListItem class, which are formatted in
>   the local time for the site. Use the DatesInUtc property of the
>   SPQuery class to use the indexer to return values in UTC format. To
>   convert values from UTC format to local time, use the UTCToLocalTime
>   method of the SPTimeZone class, which can be accessed through the
>   RegionalSettings property for the current site, as follows:
>   mySite.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.UtcTimeToLocalTime(date). To convert
>   values from local time to UTC format, instead use the LocalTimeToUTC
>   method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms197282.aspx